# Failed to add edge detection - Raspberry Pi 3 GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 model B.

I tried different approaches using both `gpiozero` and `RPi.GPIO`. The problem occurs regardless of the library used.

Here is an example of code that fails with `gpiozero`.

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def handle():
    print("Pressed!")

button = None
while not button:
    try:
        button = Button(4, pull_up=True)
        button.when_pressed = handle
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(e)
        pass

pause()
```

The line `button = Button(4, pull_up=True)` always raises a `RuntimeError` and the output of the program (running `python3`) is:

```
Failed to add edge detection
Failed to add edge detection
Failed to add edge detection
Failed to add edge detection
# ... it goes on for ages
```

I already tried to reinstall `RPi.GPIO` and `gpiozero` but it did not help.

Here is the full traceback of the exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/input_devices.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.pin.when_changed = self._fire_events
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/__init__.py", line 240, in <lambda>
    lambda self, value: self._set_when_changed(value),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 233, in _set_when_changed
    bouncetime=self._bounce)
RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection
```

Answer (score 2):

I also get the same problem on **Raspberry Pi 3 B** with **Arch_arm** operating system.
It seems that this problem has nothing to do with your Python code.

---

In Raspberrypi/linux system, you can only use the GPIO with root authority by default.

The `/dev/gpiomem` instead of `/dev/mem`, can let user use GPIO with rootless. Of course you should make some changes.

1. add new group name `gpio` && add your user account name to the group

   ```
   sudo groupadd -r gpio
   sudo usermod -a -G gpio pi
   ```
2. add udev rules to `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

   ```
   ls -l /etc/udev/rules.d
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 580 Aug  5 15:02 raspberrypi.rules
   ```

You can  add these rules below to the tail of the file `raspberrypi.rules` with sudo.

```
    SUBSYSTEM=="bcm2835-gpiomem", KERNEL=="gpiomem", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"
    SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpiochip*", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown root:gpio /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport ; chmod 220 /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport'"
    SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", KERNEL=="gpio*", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown root:gpio /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value ; chmod 660 /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value'"
```

Happy coding.

Comment: This seemed to help. However, in my case the error seems to pop up more randomly. When I restart the program it runs. Or not.

Comment: Pi 4 does not seem to have this rules file. It's got 99-com.rules. Not sure if that's the same...

Comment: Still happens after doing this, anything else I can do ? RaspPi 3 , ubuntu server 22.04

Answer (score 0):

running it with `sudo` should work

For example

```
sudo python test-gpio.py
```